# Emulating XBOX One controller on Ubuntu 18.04...?

Tags: 18.04, xinput

As the title says. I want to play some games, but they only support XInput, but I don't have an XBOX controllers, just DInput ones, that are perfectly working. I can't find any working guides for 18.04. Do you know what I can do about it? Thank you!